# CPU Percentage Utilisation in Grafana

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have Table dashboard created in grafana for CPU utilization for large number of hosts which contains max & avg value. Is it possible to create bar chart / pie chart using the data..
The result will be
0 to 1%-- number of hosts falls in this percentage utilization
1 to 5%-- '' ''
5 to 10% – '' ''
it should be displayed in pie / bar chart.
Anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Not sure if you can use a bar or pie chart. But maybe have a look at Histogram and Heatmap: http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/heatmap/

Comment: you can use sub querry  first get host name and cup utilization and create UDF https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.2/examples/anomaly_detection/#writing-a-udf for case statement ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pie chart plugin for grafana](https://grafana.com/plugins/grafana-piechart-panel/installation) and create the queries based on the threshold you're interested in.

You can use a query like this, more or less (after toggling the query edit mode in the panel editing screen):

```
SELECT mean("value") FROM "your_metric" WHERE RANGE_HERE and $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

In which the range can be `value >= 1 and value < 5`, for example.

Every query you create will be a part of the pie chart.

Comment: Tried with the below one. But its not showing the count of hosts.      SELECT last("value") FROM "metrics" WHERE ("service" = 'Linux CPU check' and  "value"<1) and $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(previous)

Comment: You can use count to aggregate (see https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/aggregate_functions/#count) if you want influx to return the amount of hosts complying to the conditions you set.

Comment: There is no count value displayed. It showing only Time & value       SELECT count(host),last("value") FROM "metrics" WHERE service = 'Linux CPU check' and  value<1 GROUP BY time(10m) limit 3;
    name: metrics
    time                count     last
    ----                -----         ----
    1521429600000000000       0.03
    1521430200000000000       0.02
    1521430800000000000       0.02